# Only changing X axis value

Tags: ios, cgrect

Im aware I can change the position of my image view like this

```
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(99, 34, 32, 32);
```

But how do I change just the x value leave the rest as they are?
I realize this is a simple question but because I don't know how to word the search Im having difficulty finding a solution. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
//capture frame
CGRect thisRect = myImageView.frame;

//modify required frame parameter (.origin.x/y, .size.width/height)
thisRect.origin.x = 0;

//set modified frame to object
[myImageView setFrame:thisRect];
```

Comment: @Rookie although this solution works I really believe that, in this case, CGRectOffSet is cleaner. Check my answer for more details.

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida : true neater but the link you provided made it seem like alot of reading. [this link on CGRectOffset](http://api.monobjc.net/html/M_Monobjc_ApplicationServices_CGRect_CGRectOffset.htm) is alot more simpler :)

Comment: @staticVoidMan agree. Was just to give a good amount of solutions for this :p

Comment: This works great as I want to change the position according to the current value. so I'm doing something like this

thisRect.origin.x += 25;

Don't see how I can do that using CGRectOffset

Comment: @Rookie : for that it should be `CGRectOffset(myImageView.frame, 25, 0)` for incrementing the value of x by 25

Comment: @TiagoAlmeida : i liked your answer though, had seen it but not used it since... well... didn't specifically need to but now i might :P

Answer (score 5):

You have some solutions to this issue but usually, if you want to simplify, you end up using a category like UIView+Position ([UIView+Position.h](http://bynomial.com/blogfiles/UIView+position.h) [UIView+Position.m](http://bynomial.com/blogfiles/UIView+position.m)) or [UIView Helpers](https://github.com/andrewroycarter/UIView-Helpers). Although this might be an overkill.

Another alternative is to use CGRect auxiliary methods like this:

```
myImageView.frame = CGRectOffset(myImageView.frame, 10, 0);
```

For more information on solutions for this problem [read this post](http://bynomial.com/blog/?p=24).

Comment: For me this is by far the cleanest and Objective-C friendly option.

Comment: this should've been an accepted answer. Much a cleaner way to do the task

Answer (score 1):

@staticVoidMan basically already said it, but if you want to keep the current scope clean and not pollute it with temporary variables, you can take advantage of a [GCC extension](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) and do this:

```
[self.view setFrame:({

    CGRect frame = [self.view frame];
    frame.origin.x = 0;
    frame;

})];
```

Note that while I said it's a GCC extension, it works fine with Clang (which, for the most parts, is compatible with GCC when it comes to these things).

Answer (score 0):

Create a new rectangle and modify the parts you want, then assign the frame to that one.

```
CGRect newFrame = myImageView.frame;
newFrame.origin.x = 49;

myImageView.frame = newFrame;
```

You can access the width similarly:

```
newFrame.size.width = 55;
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

A **Swift** alternative using an extension can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/nbasham/84ce5b1fdec949115999b738217bde65). Example from above:

```
myImageView.x = 99
```

or

```
myImageView.left = 99
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can now do:

```
view.frame = view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -100)
```

to shift up.